# What file I need to edit to change the text color in a theme?

Tags: unity, themes, gtk

After upgrading to Ubuntu 11.04 (from 10.10) with Unity, and after I've been messing around with the (gtk, I guess?) theme a little, I've encountered a little problem.

In my panel (the one with the systray) all text are gray, the same goes on for all my right click menus and so on. After googleing I've found out that I need to change the text[normal] (or something like) variable in my GTK theme. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

I've also found out that I need to edit a file in my theme `/usr/share/themes/<theme-name>`

But which file, and where in the file?
Needs to be changed to black. (Can I use hex codes, ex.: #000000 ?)

Actually I see that the text in my right click menu is black when an option is disabled. I actually need to switch those two colors - in order to get everything right. Correct?

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the theme is a system theme (installed by default), you can find it in the  `/usr/share/themes/` directory. So for example if it is Ambiance, you will find it in `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc` file.

If you have installed it on user mode you can probably find the theme in `~/.themes/` directory. Then go to the relevant themes `gtk-2/0` and open the gtkrc file.

At the top you might find a line as `gtk-color-scheme =`. There you can find the text colors.

But one can also change the color from right-click on desktop, them change background. Then under Theme tab select Customize and then after selecting the relevant theme, go to colors tab. Here you can change the text colors.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried the gui way (right clicking desktop), and tried changing the different colors. But ended up just using the Ambiance theme instead of "Radiance".

Comment: You can also use "Reset to Defaults" under the colors tab (Theme), in case you have changed colors and want to get back the original look.

Comment: Yeah I did that under the Radiance theme, but they were allready there.

Comment: Ok, then the Radiance theme should be usable.