# Connect WebKit WebView form to a Python callback?

Tags: python, application-development, gtk, webkit

I am writing a small Python and WebKit app; I am using WebKit as the UI for my app.

What I want to do is to create an interactive element in WebKit (namely a combo box or a set of clickable regions) and when the user interacts with these elements I can call a Python callback to do some processing and then update the WebKit view with new information.

Here is an example of what I want to do:

1. User is presented with a combo box of options (combo box displayed, I assume, using a HTML form in WebKit).
2. When the combo box option is selected, `on_combo_selected()` is called in my Python script which then grabs some data.
3. The data is passed to WebKit and the view is updated.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 31):

**Ways to communicate from an embedded WebKit widget to the controlling Python program**

*Gtk or Qt:*

- set `window.status` from JavaScript; trap the corresponding event in Python
- set `document.title` from JavaScript; trap the corresponding event in Python
- redirect the page to a custom URL (say, `x-my-app:thing1/thing2/thing3`); trap `navigation-policy-decision-requested` event in Python and look at the URL that's being navigated to, and deal with it if it's your custom URL scheme

*Qt only:*

- use `frame.addToJavaScriptWindowObject` to add a (specifically designed) Python object to the JavaScript global namespace; call methods on it from JavaScript. (See http://pysnippet.blogspot.com/2010/01/calling-python-from-javascript-in-pyqts.html for an example.)

*Methods which theoretically should work but in practice don't, very well*

- Fire a custom DOM event on an HTML element (which would include the document object) from JavaScript; trap that event in Python by navigating the WebKit DOM from Python and listening for events. This works, but I can't find a way of having Python be able to read custom data from the event, which means that you can't pass information other than the event having fired.

**Ways to communicate from Python to JavaScript**

- use `webview.execute_script(js_code)`. Note that if you're passing variable values in with the JS, it's a good idea to JSON encode them; that way you can worry a bit less about escaping, and JS can read JSON natively

Here's some example Gtk code:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk,WebKit
import json

w = Gtk.Window()
v = WebKit.WebView()
sw = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
w.add(sw)
sw.add(v)
w.set_size_request(400,300)
w.connect("destroy", lambda q: Gtk.main_quit())
def window_title_change(v, param):
    if not v.get_title():
        return
    if v.get_title().startswith("msgtopython:::"):
        message = v.get_title().split(":::",1)[1]
        # Now, send a message back to JavaScript
        return_message = "You chose '%s'. How interesting." % message
        v.execute_script("jscallback(%s)" % json.dumps(return_message))
v.connect("notify::title", window_title_change)
v.load_html_string("""<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>A demo</title>
<style>
body { font-family: Ubuntu, sans-serif; }
h1 { font-size: 1.3em; }
</style>
<body>
<h1>A tiny JavaScript demonstration</h1>
<form>
<p>What's your favourite thing about Jono? <select>
    <option>------choose one------</option>
    <option>his beard</option>
    <option>his infectious sense of humour</option>
    <option>his infectious diseases</option>
    <option>his guitar ability</option>
    <option>his wife</option>
</select></p>
</form>
<p id="out"></p>

<script>
document.querySelector("select").addEventListener("change", function() {
    var chosenOption = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text;
    // Now send that text back to Python by setting the title
    document.title = "msgtopython:::" + chosenOption;
}, false);
function jscallback(msg) {
    document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = msg;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
""", "file:///")
w.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 18):

It's been a while since I played with that but here's what I did:

Use something like

```
<form>
    <select  onchange="location.href='mycombo://'+this.value">
      <option>foo</option>
      <option>bar</option>
      <option>baz</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

in your HTML. So when the user selects an item a `mycombo`-URI with the selected value is called. To catch this connect a handler to your WebView's `navigation-requested` signal:

```
self.webview.connect("navigation-requested", self.on_navigation_requested)
```

In your signal handler you check if the request is for a `mycombo` URI. If so call `on_combo_selected`:

```
def on_navigation_requested(self, view, frame, req, data=None):
    uri = req.get_uri()
    scheme, path=uri.split(':', 1)
    if scheme == 'mycombo':
        self.on_combo_selected(path) 
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

To update your WebView use its `execute_script` function to run some JavaScript code that does the updates, like:

```
self.webview.execute_script("document.title='Updated!';")
```

Comment: Any idea how to retrieve post headers from `req`?