# How can I develop desktop applications using web standards?

Tags: application-development

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Developing app for Ubuntu in HTML and JS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58996/developing-app-for-ubuntu-in-html-and-js)

I want to develop applications for ubuntu using web standards such as html5, javascript css3. Webstandards are growing very fast today, one can develop cross-platform mobile applications using these easily. Every one is shifting to this since the release of html5 and css3. We can even develop online.  I know about titanium and other frameworks.

What are some applications that are cross-platform, open source and free and open in nature if possible.  The more the platforms the better, but Ubuntu specific ones which access the native Ubuntu APIs are preferred.

I know we can use quickly, but I am talking about web standards. Can i develop with qt using html5? I have seen it in qt create project wizard, but i am somewhat confused.
Can i develop using qt qml for ubuntu and other platforms?  I know that we can develop for symbyan and meego devices. but if I can for these others it will be very useful.