# Designing UI using html and css and without webkit?

Tags: application-development, gui, css, html5, python3

I want to try out developing desktop applications with the UI designed using html5,css and jquery and the back end code written in python. Is this possible? I have already tried out the WebKit but is there any other way? If it is possible can you point me to a good tutorial?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/58996/how-do-i-develop-an-ubuntu-applicatin-in-html-and-js

Comment: That qpost doesn't really answer my question. In the question I have clearly mentioned if there is any possible way OTHER than using WebKit.

Comment: Ah, didn't catch that those answers were for webkit view.

Comment: @Seth They aren't. If anything, there should be the answer mentioning a new method. It is still a duplicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

html5 and css requires web rendering engine in the background . So you have to use one of the web rendering engine . Webkit is the most commonly used web rendering engine because of its perfomence and portability , You can also try Gecko  from firefox but it is very hard to implement  when compared to webkit